# Ошибки обращения к методам прототипа

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```js
'use strict'
var collectionProto = {
  values: function() {
    return this;
  },
  count: function() {
    return this.length;
  },
  at: function(index) {
    return (index > this.length) ? this[index - 1] : null;
  },
  append: function(value) {
    (isArray(value)) ? this.concat(value): this.push(value);
  },
  removeAt: function(index) {
    if (index > this.length) {
      return false;
    }
    this.splice(index - 1, 1);
    return true;
  }
};

function Collection() {
  //this = [];
  return [];
}
Collection.prototype = collectionProto;
Collection.prototype.constructor = Collection;

var numbers = new Collection();
console.log(numbers.values());
```

Собственно, сама ошибка

> TypeError: numbers.values is not a function

И два вопроса:

1. Почему вылазит ошибка?
2. Почему нельзя написать в конструкторе `this = []`? Ведь `this` здесь
   объект, который создаёт интерпретатор по умолчанию.

Comment: Как я понимаю, все объекты которые создаёт конструктор, получают от него и прототип. В возвращаемом массиве прототип остается Array.prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы же возвращаете массив, а не создаваемый конструктором объект.
2. `this` - служебная конструкция, её нельзя переопределять. Да и какой в этом смысл?

```js
'use strict'
var collectionProto = {
    answer: 42
};

function Collection() {
  this.question = 'The Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything';
}
Collection.prototype = collectionProto;
Collection.prototype.constructor = Collection;

var numbers = new Collection();
console.log(numbers.question, numbers.answer);
```

Comment: Т.е. объекты которые я буду создавать в конструкторе вручную и затем возвращать их не будут иметь прототип, который определен в свойстве .prototype конструктора? Получается прототип по умолчанию можно задать только объекту this

Comment: Без запятых сложно понять смысл Вашего вопроса. `this` создаётся самим интерпретатором, ему устанавливается создаваемый объект. Возвращать его из конструктора не нужно, сам вернётся. В этот объект (`__proto__`) устанавливается прототип из `prototype` конструктора.

Answer (score 0):

Когда ты возвращаешь объект из конструктора, созданный объект забывается. Поэтому (при отсутствии ES6) можно заменить `__proto__` (поддерживается в IE11+):

```js
'use strict'

var collectionProto = Object.assign(Object.create(Array.prototype), {
  values: function() {
    return this;
  },
  count: function() {
    return this.length;
  },
  at: function(index) {
    return (index > this.length) ? this[index - 1] : null;
  },
  append: function(value) {
    (isArray(value)) ? this.concat(value): this.push(value);
  },
  removeAt: function(index) {
    if (index > this.length) {
      return false;
    }
    this.splice(index - 1, 1);
    return true;
  }
});

function Collection() {
  var me = [];
  me.__proto__ = this.__proto__;
  return me;
}

Collection.prototype = collectionProto;
Collection.prototype.constructor = Collection;

var numbers = new Collection();
console.log(numbers.values());
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
'use strict'
var collectionProto = {
  values: [],
  count: function() {
    return this.values.length;
  },
  at: function(index) {
    return (index > this.values.length) ? this.values[index - 1] : null;
  },
  append: function(value) {
    Array.isArray(value) ? this.values.concat(value): this.values.push(value);
  },
  removeAt: function(index) {
    if (index > this.values.length) {
      return false;
    }
    this.values.splice(index - 1, 1);
    return true;
  }
};

function Collection() {}
Collection.prototype = collectionProto;
Collection.prototype.constructor = Collection;

var numbers = new Collection();
console.log(numbers.values);

numbers.append(6757);
console.log(numbers.values);
```

Comment: Зачем в прототипе `values`, если его перекроет "своё" свойство?

Comment: Очистка переменной, на всякий случай)

Comment: Эм... что? Если в самом объекте есть переменная, то до одноименной переменной в прототипе не будет никакого доступа, все манипуляции будут проходить именно со своей переменной. Что там очищать? :)

Comment: Эй, за что негативная оценка? За неопытность? Почему? Код же работает. И почему ответом является всего лишь демонстрация работы класса?

Comment: К сожалению, нельзя заставить минусующих всегда пояснять за что минус.

Comment: А очень жаль...

Comment: Были попытки заставить добавлять минус, но решено что минус - привилегия индивидуальная, а заставлять кого-то управлять его личной вещью очень глупо, как лезть в личную жизнь :)